# Java FX can't import InteliJ

Tags: javafx, import, module, sdk

So l just started learning Java FX and l tried to create a file.

1. I have [Java SDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPl1W.png)
2. I downloaded the Java FX SDK and l imported it to [global libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vH7Wm.png). I even imported it to [project libraries.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6C0lu.png)
3. I did the [VM option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUy4q.png) --module-path
   C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Coding\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib
   --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml

[Here is how my project looks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9fiR.png)

Nothing fixed my problem. I tried with the newest Java FX SDK but it too didn't fix it. I tried importing from the .rar, l tried importing from a folder, l tried different VM module options, watched multiple tutorials and read multiple stackoverflow posts but nothing helped...

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind l fixed it! I tried again with the newest FX SDK and l needed to only import it in project library not in global library!